# Cannot launch selenium standalone server

Tags: selenium-grid

After succesfully setting up selenium webdriver with testng, I want to move to Selenium grid 2.
I have downlaoded the selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar file, however when runnning this :

java –jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar –role hub

I got this error :

Error: Could not find or load main class ûjar

I have set my env variables as follow :

CLASSPATH :

C:\Selenium grid\selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar;C:\selenium-2.35.0\selenium-java-2.35.0.jar

PATH :

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;C:\Selenium grid\

Please could you help me setting up grid 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my batch script for running hub and node. Script is executed where are placed selenium jars.

As you see variable `HERE` should point to Java folder

```
 set HERE=%CD%
set CHROME_VERSION=chromedriver_win_23.0.1240.0
set CHROME_DRIVER_LOC=%HERE%\%CHROME_VERSION%\chromedriver.exe
set JAVA_HOME=%HERE%\jdk1.7.0_10
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%HERE%\%CHROME_VERSION%\;%PATH%
set SELENIUM_VERSION=2.28.0

set HUB_URL=http://192.198.1.102:4444/grid/register

start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-%SELENIUM_VERSION%.jar -role hub
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-%SELENIUM_VERSION%.jar -role node 
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver= %CHROME_DRIVER_LOC% -hub %HUB_URL% -port 5556   -nodeConfig webconfig.txt
```

EDIT for comment:

So here is folder tree to clearly understand what is happening

```
 -|
  |-selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar
  |-chromedriver_win_23.0.1240.0
    |-chromedriver.exe
  |-jdk1.7.0_10
    |-jre
    |-bin etc..
  |-thisScript.bat
```

This script should be totally independent from PATH setting mentioned in your question.
PATH variable overrides system PATH variable only for that script - personally you can try different configuration and paths but I was only using above setup and it worked as intended.

I also found tutorial what I had been using when setting up my selenium grid enviroment:
http://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/setting-up-grid2-and-working-with-it/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so from your script I can conclude that I don't need to create a new env variable that points to the selenium server jar file? I am trying to understand the logic behind this as I frequently facing issue setting this up. Should I delete the class path variable or point it to the JAVA folder?

Comment: See updated answer - if you have more questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: So cool - as stackoverflow user you can give this answer vote up and mark tick if it resolved your problem - that is reward for good answers - see more on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of selenium, say 2.39.0 from the seleniumHQ.org site.

Place it in C:\ drive. Goto the environment variables and add **java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar** to the classpath

Open Command prompt and then navigate to the C:\ drive where you placed the jar and type **java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub**

Press enter

After this, you would get something like this

C:>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub
Feb 05, 2014 12:51:15 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid server
2014-02-05 12:51:17.517:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2014-02-05 12:51:17.554:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
2014-02-05 12:51:17.564:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4444